# New-PSSession and Runspacepool clarification

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

I need to run Exchange online cmdlets using powershell classes in C#.

To run exchange online cmdlets i need to establish a remote powershell session.

My doubts are:
1) If runspacepool size is 2, **should i create that remote powershell session in both the runspaces in that runspacepool?** If yes, how can I / Is there a way to loop through the runspaces to run the New-PSSession command in both the runspaces.

2) If session expires in ONE runspace, is there a way to get that particular runspace from the runspacepool, and create new session that runspace alone?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually create remote sessions for each runspace in the pool. Instead, supply connection information when instantiating the runspacepool with the following overload: [`RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool(Int32, Int32, RunspaceConnectionInfo)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd127638(v=vs.85).aspx) (as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913254/how-to-establish-and-enter-a-remote-session-using-runspace-in-powershell)):

```
string shell = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";
var target = new Uri("http://myserver/wsman");
var secured = new SecureString();
foreach (char letter in "mypassword")
{
    secured.AppendChar(letter);
}
secured.MakeReadOnly();

var credential = new PSCredential("username", secured);
var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(target, shell, credential);

Runspace remotePool = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool(0,2,connectionInfo);
```

Comment: Hi Mathias R. Jessen, Consider using that runspacepool, i run exchange online cmdlets. But i dont have control which runspace in that runspacepool will run that cmdlet. There is a chance that remote pssession will expire in one runspace alone? at that time i should abandon this runspacepool and create a new runspacepool? (bcoz i cant run cmdlet to create new pssession in the session expired particular runspace)

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't think you need to worry about that. Btw, the shell schema would be `http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange` for Exchange Online

Comment: you mean to say, session will not expire at all (or) even if session expires, it will be established automatically?